# Render limit from json file

Tags: reactjs

Im trying to render 4 items from a local json file. I will use it so i can show the newest products in a section. In the catalog can be 1000 of items, but i only need to render example the newest 4 items. I have made a local json file with 6 items for the purpose and i need to render the newest 4 items eg. item3, item4, item5 and item6.

Can someone point me in the right direction or even better - show me an example? What is the best and cleanest way to handle this scenario using react.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
// Components
import GridItemProduct from './../components/grid-items/GridItemProduct'
import ContentContainer from '../components/ContentContainer'
import GridContainer from '../components/GridContainer'

// Data
import data from '../data/data.json'
const productData = data.products;

class FrontpageRoute extends Component {
    render() {     
        return (
            <div className="frontpage-route">

                <ContentContainer>
                    <GridContainer columnCount="four">
                        {productData.map(item => 
                            <GridItemProduct 
                                key={item.id}
                                id={item.id}
                                title={item.title}
                                description={item.description}
                                price={item.price}
                                currency={item.currency}
                                url={item.url}
                            />
                        )} 
                    </GridContainer>
                </ContentContainer>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default FrontpageRoute
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `slice(array.length - 4)` before you map the array:

```
productData.slice(productData.length - 4).map(item => ...
```

Comment: I fixed the [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) syntax, otherwise good advice

Comment: Thanks @Aprillion, i forgot change the array name

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you. Would this also be a good way to do it if the json data had like 1000+ items?

Comment: As i know complexity of slice O(N) where N is end-start index. So there should not be a difference.